# vulnerabilities of letting user define innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Let's say I have a <textarea> and <div> element, and when the user puts html, CSS, or whatever they want), into the textarea, then their input is set as the innerHTML of the <div> element, using javascript.

What are the vulnerabilities of letting the user define the content of a <div> element?

Comment: are you talking about a live preview sort of thing here?

Comment: @Demian Yes, the div would render the html as you type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the content they enter does not leave the page, there is no more risk than them editing the DOM through firebug or the chrome inspector.  If you take their input and then display it as is, that is a huge security risk especially when other users are on your website.

Comment: for the content they enter to "not leave the page", would I have to use an `iframe`?

Comment: No, you just handle the submit button click, grab the textarea text, and set a div's innerHTML to that value, in your case.

Comment: I'm still not understanding what you are saying :( If you put the textarea text as the div's innerHTML then wouldn't that be vulnerable to malicious JavaScript?

Comment: Not if you don't send the text the user entered to the server.  If you just keep it on that page, there is no risk.  They can just open up their inspector and just mess with the HTML themselves anyways (you can't ever stop this, I can do it to this page right now if I want).  If you process their text and then display it for other users, that is where you and your users become vulnerable.

Comment: Excellent, Thank you! It all makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you encode the contents so that any javascript that is in there won't execute then it should be  safe.

If you don't then a user could upload javascript that would execute the next time another user views that page.

I want to modify my response to take into account @Brigham comments. Escape only works reliably if you are dealing with the the innerHTML of something like a div tab, if you are dealing with using a user generated value as a attribute or within a script tag then escaping/encoding won't work.

I'll refer you to the OWASP XSS guidance (that @Brigham originally brought to my attention) for more information: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Untrusted_Data

Comment: Encoding the contents to remove the possibility of Javascript is fairly difficult. For example, in IE, it's possible to run Javascript in CSS: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.234_-_CSS_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Style_Property_Values

Comment: @Brigham, thanks for that link it's very interesting. I will definitely be using it as a reference. However, this particular question is not about placing user input in an arbitrary position in the document. The question is specifically about replacing the body of the div. In this case encoding should take care of all the possible attacks. Even the document you refenced states this: "HTML entity encoding is okay for untrusted data that you put in the body of the HTML document, such as inside a <div> tag. "

Answer (score 0):

The user can do cross-site scripting. It can inject malicious client-side code

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the OP is talking about a live preview of what the user is typing, in which case why would one want to run anything malicious on their own machine (not to mention that this functionality is not consistent with the definition of XSS)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever they want could include a `<script>` tag which pulls a .js file from their own server. Then if you show that content to another user, the script could do all kinds of things to extract information from the unsuspecting user.